# Modifying the webconfig file of multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to modify the web config file of all projects in a particular folder  by adding a new line in web config? can any suggest how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small console app, with something like that :

```
var path = <YourDirectory>;
var newValue = <a new Value in the new line>;
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "web.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in files)
{
   var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
   var parentElement = doc.Element("blabla");//get the right parent Node
   parentElement.Add(new XElement("new name"), newValue);//well put what you want in it : attributes, values...
   doc.Save(file);
}
```

**EDIT**

For your case, just put that in the main

```
var path = @"C:\Tools";
var newAssembly = @"System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "Web.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in files)
{
      var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
      var parentElement = doc.Descendants("assemblies").FirstOrDefault();
      if (parentElement != null)
      {
           var newNode = new XElement("add", new XAttribute("assembly", newAssembly));
           parentElement.Add(newNode);
      }
                doc.Save(file);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to add  assembly reference in  multiple asp.net mvc projects using a console application ?

Comment: for modifying the project file for adding assembly reference, this code snipped not working. is there anyother way?